max eigenvalue and schatten-1 norm of depolarizing channel acting on trace-0 Hermitian matrix
Denote $\mathcal{H}^n$ as the $n-$dimension Hermitian matrices. Depolarizing channel $\Delta_p:\mathcal{H}^2\to\mathcal{H}^2$ is defined as $\Delta_p(A)=p\text{ tr }(A)~I/2+(1-p)A$ where $A\in \mathcal{H}^2$. It is obvious that if $tr(A)=0,\lambda_{max}(\Delta_p(A))=(1-p)\lambda_{max}(A)$ and $\text{tr}(|\Delta_p(A)|)=(1-p)\text{tr}(|A|)$. Here $Tr(|A|)$ is the sum of the absolute value of eigenvalues of $A$.
Consider the depolarizing channel $\Delta_p^{\otimes2}:\mathcal{H}^4\to\mathcal{H}^4$. If $B\in \mathcal{H}^4$ and $B=\sum_i C_i\otimes D_i$, where $C_i,D_i\in\mathcal{H}^2 $ and $\otimes$ is the Kronecker Product, $\Delta_p^{\otimes2}(B)=\sum_i \Delta_p(C_i)\otimes \Delta_p(D_i)$.
My question is if $tr(B)=0$, do the following statements hold true: $\lambda_{max}(\Delta_p^{\otimes 2}(B))\leq(1-p)\lambda_{max}(B)$ and $\text{tr}(|\Delta_p^{\otimes 2}(B)|)\leq(1-p)\text{tr}(|B|)$?
Define $\sigma_0=I$and $\{\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3\}=\{X,Y,Z\}$ here $X,Y,Z$ are pauli matrices. $\{I,X,Y,Z\}$ form a basis $\mathcal{H}^2$ if the inner product of two matrices is the trace of their product. For $B\in\mathcal{H}^4$, suppose $B=\sum_{ij}b_{ij}\sigma_i\otimes\sigma_j$. Then it can be verified that $\Delta_p^{\otimes2}(B)=\sum_{ij}b_{ij}(1-p)^{w(ij)}\sigma_i\otimes\sigma_j$ where $w(ij)$ is the number of nonzero numbers of $\{ij\}$. For example $w(00)=0,w(03)=w(20)=1,w(23)=2$. If $\text{tr}(B)=0$ then $b_{00}=0$ and every term of the decomposition of $\Delta_p^{\otimes2}(B)$ will have a factor of $1-p$ or $(1-p)^2$.
